# Fine-Tuning T5 with specific penalty

Tags: transformer, machine-translation, fine-tuning

Currently I am finetuning `transformers` T5 model for translation task. As part of the dataset, I am given sentences in Japanese, their translation to English, and for every English sentence I am also given a few (English) words which need to be in the translated sentence.

Is there a way to modify the `Seq2SeqTrainer` and the loss being used in order to penalize the model (while training) for not including the given words in the translated sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I encountered this issue myself.

My solution was to wrap the model in my own class.
I then overrode the forward method. ( I was using pytorch lightning)

```
class WrapModel(pl.LightningModule):
    self.model = T5ForConditionalGeneration...

def forward(self, **inputs):
    outputs = self.model(**inputs)
    loss = new_loss_logic(outputs.specific_hidden_state)
    outputs.loss = loss
```

I am relatively new to the field, but I think this should work.
If you wish to stay within HF, you can always make the wrapping class inherit the T5Model, then the call to the underlying `forward` is `self(**inputs)` or can be down with `super()`, but the rest remains the same